# Nested servlet mapping (/myname/servletname)

Tags: jsp, servlets, build, mapping

I'm writing a web.xml to deploy my Java servlet. The .war file is copied to a directory called "/myname/servletname" on the server. I'm trying to access the servlet at server.com:8080/myname/servletname

Web.xml is as follows currently

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>connect4.GameBoardBean</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>myname/servletname</servlet-name>
```

And the copy routine for the war file in build.xml:

```
<copy file ="servletname.war"  todir = "/opt/jboss/server/default/deploy/myname"/>
```

I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access the URL. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see it, myname is the context path. So it shouldn't be in the mapping. Keep only /servletname in web.xml